# Vercel Next.js build error while prerendering pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm running Vercel compilation on my website and I can't get rid of the pre-rendering error on export.
does anyone know the reason for this to happen and can help me with this?
my github with all code: https://github.com/M0rilla/MyProfile

for each page have a error as above:

```
    Error occurred prerendering page "/resume". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
21:20:09.541        /
21:20:09.541        /404
21:20:09.541        /500
21:20:09.541        /experiences
21:20:09.542        /resume
21:20:09.542        /skills
```

i dont have a custom 404 or 500 page.

Comment: The reason this is happening (invalid react hook call) is stated directly in the error link. If you aren't sure why your react hook call is invalid after reading the information there, make sure to put the code of your `/resume` page here, otherwise there's no way we can help.

Comment: I added the code for one of my pages for viewing. All pages contained in the "pages" directory are showing this error including 404 and 500 that I did not create

Comment: There's a link to my github with the project on the question!

Comment: While I can't test your code with a Vercel deployment, your issue is almost certainly caused by you committing your `node_modules` folder and `.next` build artifacts to git, which you should _never_ do. You should create a `.gitignore` file with `node_modules/` and `.next/`. See https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: can you create a answer with this comment? my production code is now working fine! adding the gitignore file and deleting these folders from repo saved me. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vercel does some custom work in regards to next builds, so committing the `.next` build artifacts from your local machine or your `node_modules` folder can interfere with the build in unpredictable ways that give seemingly nonsensical error messages. Make sure to not commit either `.next` or `node_modules` to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking these cases:

- Make sure to move any non-pages out of the pages folder
- Check for any code that assumes a prop is available even when it might not be. e.g., have default data for all dynamic pages' props.
- Check for any out of date modules that you might be relying on
- Make sure your component handles fallback if it is enabled in getStaticPaths. Fallback docs
- Make sure you are not trying to export (next export) pages that have server-side rendering enabled (getServerSideProps)

([source](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error))

Comment: inside "pages" the only non-page is the _app.js. i will add the code to the question. I'm new to Next.js so i can't have sure about the other situations.